# Get all environment variables in Dlang

Tags: environment-variables, d, environment

https://dlang.org/library/std/process/environment.html allows getting a particular environment variable.

But I see no way to get all environment variables or the list of all environment variable names.

What is the right way to retrieve the full environment in D?

In fact, I want to pass some environment variables to a child process. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Oh, I found: method `toAA()`

Comment: But `toAA` is relatively inefficient. Is there are more efficient way?

Comment: If you're manipulating environment variables often enough for `toAA` to be a bottleneck, you're doing something wrong - have you considered using regular variables inside your tight loops? :p

Comment: If you want to do something faster, you're going to have to use the `environ` ptr (posix) or `GetEnvironmentStringsW` (Windows) directly, as is being done in `toAA`: https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/master/std/process.d#L3513

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to get all variables to pass to a child process; that is the default. If you are using the std.process library, you can pass null for environment to keep the existing one entirely, or a set of just the keys and values you want to change to get just them changed, and the rest inherited.

Comment: I do not use `std.process`. I use (also authored by myself) C library libcomcom - https://github.com/vporton/libcomcom

Comment: You can do it the same as C; environment variables aren't D specific. You can also look at the std.process implementation of `createEnv` https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/master/std/process.d#L784